# User authentication and browser back/forward buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Asp.net MVC 3 in my project. I have a simple login page which takes username and password and after successful login, take me to the required page.

The problem is when I press **back** button from my browser and then press **forward** button again and again, it takes me again to the page without getting username and password from the user.

I don't know, may be it is the problem with sessions state. Because I didn't make any sessions and I don't how to make it.

Please anyone out there help me a bit to mitigate this problem.

Comment: You press *Back* on which page? *It gets you back to the page*? Which page? Describe your scenario step by step. And what does this have to do with EF?

Comment: Show some code of your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Your session id is stored in a cookie, on successful authentication, the cookie gets stored on your machine, when you move forward in history, it doesn't get removed.

If you explicitly clear the cookie on each visit to the login page using:

```
Session.Abandon()
```

this will kill the authenticated session and create a new anonymous one, which shouldn't have access to the restricted page

Comment: where do i have to write Session.Abandon()  ?

Comment: when i put Session.Abandon() method in my login ActionResult method.

Comment: User authentication should have nothing to do with Session.

Comment: [HttpPost] public ActionResult Log(Admin model)
        {

            if (model.name == "admin" && model.pass == "pakistan")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ViewForAdmin", "Admin");
               // FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.name, false);
                //Session.Abandon();
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user login or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
            return View(model);
               // return RedirectToAction("LogError", "Admin");
        }